# Is the expression (fileNew == NULL) always true?

Tags: c++

I am teaching myself c++ (and c), and one way I am learning is by deconstructing (and fixing) a program for the pi that is used to connect to a bluetooth OBD reader and give readouts on a display in the car.

My question: In this program I find the line

```
if(fileNew == NULL || fileOld == NULL) fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Could not edit dhcpcd");
```

Is this expression not ALWAYS true? As I understand it, if I am opening a new file to record information, it will be NULL until I have placed information in the file. If I do understand it correctly, then would the program not always respond by sending the message to stderr, and in turn, because of the logic of this program, fail to open fileNew?  Both fileOld and fileNew are given unique names in the fopen commands immediately preceding this line.

I have searched for an answer online, and anything that comes up refers to javascript. In all the results I examined the expression NULL was not present. There were no similar questions here. I have read through the textboot I am using as best I can and have not found the answer. I have done research.

Comment: In C++ prefer `nullptr` to C's `NULL`.

Comment: You forgot to tell what `fileNew` is.

Comment: as noted in the comment fileNew is named in the preceding line. In this case, it is /etc/dhcpcd.new.

Comment: Right, but you haven't shown the preceding line. I'm guessing it's `fileNew = fopen( .. )` ?

Comment: It helps us if you include at least the type of the variables referenced in your code, be they `FILE*` or `std::ifstream`. A more complete example would have helped resolve that ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to include more info next time. Just getting a handle on HOW to ask questions, really. I definitely didn't understand the pointer portion of this.

Answer (score 2):

If you successfully open a file the file handle (pointer) will be non-null. If you're using [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) you'll get a non-`NULL` handle if the operation was successful, `NULL` if the operation failed.

Think about it: How can you use a pointer that's null, and how could that pointer spontaneously non-nullify itself when you write to it?

In C++ it's usually more convenient to use the [Standard Library IO streams](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io#Stream-based_I.2FO) to do file writing.

Comment: Thank you. I am an absolute beginner and did not understand that concept. I'm sorry if I offended people by being a newbie.

Comment: It's not offending anyone, just trying to explain how to think about it. Remember, if you're ever stumped by some code and don't know how it's working drop it into a debugger and step through it line by line. This usually provides a lot more insight than reading man pages and wondering. C++, and C as well, behave in non-intuitive ways, so the debugger is an essential tool to fully understanding what your code does.

Comment: So here, the preceding line        ```fileNew = fopen("/etc/dhcpcd.new", "w");```    opens and names the file, in write mode, and the if statement is checking that the new file opened correctly?

Comment: I get it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No.

A null file pointer does not mean "the file is empty". It means "this pointer is not valid; it does not represent a handle to an open file stream".

If you perform `fopen`, and the operation succeeds, it returns you a `FILE*` that acts as a handle to the file stream. Whether there is data in the file or not is irrelevant.

You then *use* that handle (`fileNew`, I guess, in your example) to do whatever you want with the file, be it reading or writing or whatever.

The pointer will be `NULL` if the `fopen` call failed for some reason (e.g. insufficient permissions), because [that's what the designers of `fopen` decided](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html).

**tl;dr a file pointer and a file are two different things.**